# How do a send a pdf using a docusign restful api in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, docusignapi

I need to know how to send a stamped pdf to receiptants for digital signing.  The pdf is stamped using itextsharp

do I need an envelope id for the api?  How do I attach the stamped pdf for sending using docusign?

Function

```
Private pdfFormFileName As String = "myAcrobatFormFile.pdf"

Sub Print_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As CommandEventArgs)
    Dim sUniqueKey As String
    Dim dr As OdbcDataReader
    Dim sql As String
    Dim reader As PdfReader
    Dim sFileName As String = ""

    Dim sArray As Array

    sUniqueKey = e.CommandArgument
    sArray = sUniqueKey.Split(",")

    sql = "select "
    sql += "name,"
    sql += "id"
    sql += " from table"
    sql += " where key1=" & sArray(0)
    sql += " and key2=" & sArray(1)

    oFnc.OpenODBC()

    selectCommand = New OdbcCommand(sql, oFnc.connWeb)
    dr = selectCommand.ExecuteReader
    If dr.Read Then

        reader = New PdfReader(server.mappath(pdfFormFileName))

        sFileName = "data/" & oFnc.GetTimeStamp & "displayForm.pdf"

        Dim stamper As PdfStamper = New PdfStamper(reader, New System.IO.FileStream(Server.MapPath(sFileName), FileMode.Create))


        Dim fields As AcroFields
        fields = stamper.AcroFields


        With fields
            .SetField("txtName", Left(dr("name"), 20))
            .SetField("txtId", dr("id")
        End With
        stamper.FormFlattening = True
        stamper.Close()

    End If
    dr.Close()

    oFnc.CloseODBC()
End Sub
```

How to send this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<envelopeDefinition          
xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-      
instance"xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<emailBlurb>Annual contract</emailBlurb>
<emailSubject>API Call for adding signature request to document and     
sending</emailSubject>
<status>sent</status>
<documents>
  <document>
     <documentId>1</documentId>
     <name>myAcrobatFormFile.pdf</name>
  </document>
</documents>
<recipients>
  <signers>
     <signer>
        <recipientId>2</recipientId>
        <email>abc@gmail.com</email>
        <name>Bob Smith</name>
     </signer>
  </signers>
</recipients>
</envelopeDefinition>
```

Comment: read this its might be helpful http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14488/E-signing-PDF-documents-with-iTextSharp

Comment: I have the PDF stamper code working, currently.  The PDF just needs the digital signature by docusign.  I need the restful api code for sending the pdf.

Comment: I read the code project and it was not what I want.  I do not want to add a signed signature to the pdf through stamper.  I do want to send a docusign pdf that has been stamped for the recepient to digitally sign using the docusign cloud.

Comment: I need the restful api to create an envelop and send a pdf out.  see this link  http://community.docusign.com/t5/DocuSign-API-Integration-Ruby-Salesforce-and-Other-READ-ONLY/Getting-Docusign-Connect-to-work-with-a-custom-integration-from/td-p/14057

Comment: templates would work if I didnt need to stamp the pdf.  http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/embeddedSending

Comment: how do I create a signature request using the docusign restful api in asp.net.  https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/quick-start/request-signatures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub login_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    'Dim oClient = New WebClient
    Dim sUrl As String = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v1/login_information?api_password=true&include_account_id_guid=true&login_settings=all"
    Dim sEmail As String = "abc@gmail.com"
    Dim sPassword As String = "mypassword"
    Dim sIntegratorKey As String = "myintegratorkey"
    Dim sDocumentName As String = "mypdfdocument.pdf"
    Dim sContentType As String = "application/pdf"

    Dim oRequest As HttpWebRequest
    oRequest = initializeRequest(sUrl, "GET", "", sEmail, sPassword, sIntegratorKey)


    Dim oResponse As HttpWebResponse = oRequest.GetResponse
    Dim baseURL As String = ""
    Dim oStreamReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(oResponse.GetResponseStream)
    Dim sXML As String = oStreamReader.ReadToEnd
    baseURL = parseDataFromResponse(sXML, "baseUrl")
    Dim sXmlBody As String
    sXmlBody = "<envelopeDefinition xmlns='http://www.docusign.com/restapi'>" & _
                "<emailSubject>DocuSign API</emailSubject>" & _
                "<status>sent</status>" & _
                "<documents>" & _
                "<document>" & _
                "<documentId>1</documentId>" & _
                "<name>" & sDocumentName & "</name>" & _
                "</document>" & _
                "</documents>" & _
                "<recipients>" & _
                "<signers>" & _
                "<signer>" & _
                "<recipientId>1</recipientId>" & _
                "<email>jsmith@abc.com</email>" & _
                "<name>John Smith</name>" & _
                "<tabs>" & _
                "<signHereTabs>" & _
                "<signHere>" & _
                "<xPosition>100</xPosition>" & _
                "<yPosition>100</yPosition>" & _
                "<documentId>1</documentId>" & _
                "<pageNumber>1</pageNumber>" & _
                "</signHere>" & _
                "</signHereTabs>" & _
                "</tabs>" & _
                "</signer>" & _
                "</signers>" & _
                "</recipients>" & _
                "</envelopeDefinition>"

    sUrl = baseURL & "/envelopes"

    oRequest = initializeRequest(sUrl, "POST", "", sEmail, sPassword, sIntegratorKey)

    configureMultiPartFormDataRequest(oRequest, sXmlBody, sDocumentName, sContentType)

    Dim sMessage As String
    sMessage = getResponseBody(oRequest)
    MsgBox(sMessage)
    'Dim sUri As String = parseDataFromResponse(sXML, "uri")

End Sub
Function getResponseBody(ByRef oRequest As HttpWebRequest) As String
    Dim oResponse As HttpWebResponse = oRequest.GetResponse
    Dim oStreamReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(oResponse.GetResponseStream)
    Dim sResponseString As String = oStreamReader.ReadToEnd
    Return (sResponseString)
End Function

Sub configureMultiPartFormDataRequest(ByRef oRequest As HttpWebRequest, sXmlBody As String, sDocumentName As String, sContentType As String)
    oRequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=BOUNDARY"
    Dim sRequestBodyStart As String = "\r\n\r\n--BOUNDARY\r\n" & _
      "Content-Type: application/xml\r\n" & _
                "Content-Disposition: form-data\r\n" & _
                "\r\n" & _
                sXmlBody & "\r\n\r\n--BOUNDARY\r\n" & _
                "Content-Type: " & sContentType & "\r\n" & _
                "Content-Disposition: file; filename='" & sDocumentName & "'; documentId=1\r\n" & _
                "\r\n"
    Dim sRequestBodyEnd As String = "\r\n--BOUNDARY--\r\n\r\n"
    Dim oFileStream As FileStream = File.OpenRead(Server.MapPath(sDocumentName))
    Dim bodyStart As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sRequestBodyStart.ToString)
    Dim bodyEnd As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sRequestBodyEnd.ToString)
    Dim oDataStream As Stream = oRequest.GetRequestStream
    oDataStream.Write(bodyStart, 0, sRequestBodyStart.ToString.Length())
    Dim buffer(4096) As Byte
    Dim iLen As Integer = 0
    iLen = oFileStream.Read(buffer, 0, 4096)
    Do While iLen > 0
        oDataStream.Write(buffer, 0, iLen)
        iLen = oFileStream.Read(buffer, 0, 4096)
    Loop

    oDataStream.Write(bodyEnd, 0, sRequestBodyEnd.ToString.Length())
    oDataStream.Close()

End Sub

Function initializeRequest(sUrl As String, sMethod As String, sBody As String, sEmail As String, sPassword As String, sIntegratorKey As String) As HttpWebRequest
    Dim oRequest As HttpWebRequest

    oRequest = WebRequest.Create(sUrl)
    oRequest.KeepAlive = False
    oRequest.Method = sMethod

    AddRequestHeaders(oRequest, sEmail, sPassword, sIntegratorKey)
    If sBody <> "" Then
        AddRequestBody(oRequest, sBody)
    End If


    Return (oRequest)
End Function
Sub AddRequestHeaders(ByRef oRequest As HttpWebRequest, sEmail As String, sPassword As String, sIntegratorKey As String)
    oRequest.Headers.Add("X-DocuSign-Authentication",
        String.Format("<DocuSignCredentials><Username>{0}</Username><Password>{1}</Password><IntegratorKey>{2}</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>", sEmail, sPassword, sIntegratorKey))

    oRequest.Accept = "application/xml"
    oRequest.ContentType = "application/xml"
End Sub
Sub addRequestBody(ByRef oRequest As HttpWebRequest, sRequestBody As String)
    Dim body As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sRequestBody)
    Dim oDataStream As Stream = oRequest.GetRequestStream
    oDataStream.Write(body, 0, sRequestBody.Length)
    oDataStream.Close()

End Sub
Function parseDataFromResponse(sXML As String, sSearchToken As String) As String
    Dim oXmlReader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(New StringReader(sXML))
    Do While oXmlReader.Read()
        If oXmlReader.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Element And oXmlReader.Name = sSearchToken Then
            Return oXmlReader.ReadString()
        End If
    Loop
    Return ""
End Function
```

Comment: The file stream reads the pdf into the request stream and then attempts to post it.  The server rejects the post but the error message is not clear.

Comment: How to request a signature?http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/requestSignatureFromDocument

Answer (score 1):

The DocuSign API Walkthroughs that you have found are great examples of how to do this, and the API Explorer is another great tool that shows you how the REST calls are made.  Both of these can be found on the API Tools page in the Developer Center:

https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/quick-start/api-explorer

The API Explorer allows you to make any API call without writing any code.  You just enter your credentials at the top of the page, select which call you want to make, fill out parameters (if needed), and hit the TRY IT button.

Unfortunately the API Walkthroughs do not have Visual Basic examples.  However there are C# examples (another .NET technology), more particularly this example for requesting a signature on a local file:

http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/requestSignatureFromDocument